# Running shell command in QT c++ in ubuntu

Tags: qt, shell

I am using Qt 5.0.1 (64 bit) in ubuntu. 
I am running the following command under button pressed function.

QString command = "sh /home/rahul/qtapp/ques_new/ques_new/inter4ql/test1.sh";
const char* command2;

command2 = command.toLocal8Bit().data();

### system(command2);

test1.sh file content is

## !/bin/bash

echo "hello" 
echo "hello" >> out.txt

---

While calling this system command by pressing button, it shows hello  in the output window, but it doesnot create new file out.txt.

For debugging I manually create out.txt before calling this function. But, after calling this function again it shows hello on output window but doesnot put hello in out.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong.

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello" >> out.txt
```

Worked without any problems here.

Also, the file might not being created at directory you're looking at. Have you checked your script directory and your application working directory? Replace the `out.txt` with a full path (`/home/derp/out.txt`, for example).